# Only one handle with JQuery range slider

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui, coffeescript

i try to implement a slider on my site with jQuery Slider. The 'normal' slider works fine but at the range slider the max handle is missing.

The HTML:

```
<dd id="search-diameter">
              <div class="variable-range">
                <span class="lower">7.5</span>
                <span class="upper">11.0</span>
                mm
                <div id="slider-diameter" class="slider"></div>
              </div>
    </dd>
```

The CSS:

```
.slider {
margin-left: 0.6em;
margin-right: 0.6em;
}

.ui-slider.ui-slider-horizontal .ui-slider-handle {
background: url("sliders.png") no-repeat scroll center top transparent;
border: medium none;
cursor: pointer;
height: 20px;
margin: 0 0 3px -8px;
outline: medium none !important;
top: -6px;
width: 20px;
}
```

And the CoffeeScript:

```
$('#slider-diameter').slider
min: 7.5
max: 11.0
range: true
step: 0.1
value: [7.5, 11.0]
slide: (event, ui) ->
  $("#search-diameter .lower").text ui.values[0]
  $("#search-diameter .upper").text ui.values[1]
```

After that it looks:
[image]

Comment: Might be worth pasting the coffescript into the 'try coffescript' window on the coffecript site to see what js it outputs. I know it can be a bit annoying with indending sometimes. I would however call slider like this: $('#slider-diameter').slider({ options/settings object })

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `values` not `value` if you want to supply both values for a range slider. From the [fine manual](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Slider#option-value):

> **value** Number
>
> Determines the value of the slider, if there's only one handle. If there is more than one handle, determines the value of the first handle.

and [also](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Slider#option-values):

> **values** Array
>
> This option can be used to specify multiple handles. If range is set to true, the length of 'values' should be 2.

The problem is that you're using `value` with an array but it is expecting a number. You should be saying:

```
values: [7.5, 11.0]
# ---^
```

For example: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/PrHyV/

Comment: @ThreeFingerMark: Well the interface is a bit stupid too so don't feel bad. There's no good reason for both `value` and `values`, there's even [`$.isArray`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.isArray/) so there's no reason they couldn't just use `value` and do The Right Thing with an array.